# Coloring faces , vertices ,edges of a cube using $3$ colors

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math, coloring, cubics

> We have a classical cube  with six faces , eight vertices and twelve edges . We want to color faces ,vertices and edges of this cube using three colors. How many non-equivalent coloring are there ?

**My work** I  calculated that $$\frac{1}{24}\bigg[x_1^{26}+6x_1^2x_4^6 +9x_1^2x_2^{12} +8x_1^2x_3^8\bigg]$$   $$\frac{1}{24}\bigg[3^{26}+6(3^8) +9(3^{14}) +8(3^{10})\bigg]=11769712290$$

Is my solution correct ?

Answer (score 1):

What we need to verify here is the cycle index of the action of the
rotations of the cube on the faces, vertices and edges simultaneously.

We first get the identity, wich contributes (use $a$ for faces, $b$ for
vertices and $c$ for edges):

$$a_1^6 b_1^8 c_1^{12}.$$

There are rotations about an axis passing through opposite faces (three
such axes) which fix those faces, giving

$$3\times (2a_1^2 a_4 b_4^2 c_4^3 + a_1^2 a_2^2 b_2^4 c_2^6).$$

There are rotations about axes passing through opposite vertices (four
such axes), giving

$$4 \times 2 a_3^2 b_1^2 b_3^2 c_3^4.$$

Finally there are rotations about axes passing through the midpoints of
pairs of opposite edges (six such pairs), which contribute

$$6\times a_2^3 b_2^4 c_1^2 c_2^5.$$

Collecting everything we get the cycle index

$$\frac{1}{24} (x_1^{26} + 6 x_1^2 x_4^6
+ 3 x_1^2 x_2^{12} + 8 x_1^2 x_3^8
+ 6 x_1^2 x_2^{12})
\\ = \frac{1}{24} (x_1^{26} + 6 x_1^2 x_4^6
+ 9 x_1^2 x_2^{12} + 8 x_1^2 x_3^8).$$

We have verified the cycle index by OP. We get the sequence for
colorings with at most $n$ colors

$$1, 2802752, 105912891117, 187650085502976, 62088173933203125,
\ldots$$

This is the polynomial

$$A_n = \frac{1}{24} (n^{26}+9 n^{14} +8 n^{10}+6 n^8).$$

We can also compute $B_n$ giving colorings  with exactly $n$ colors using
PIE. Here  the underlying poset has nodes  $Q\subseteq [n]$ with weight
$(-1)^{n-|Q|}$ that represent colorings  using some subset of the colors in
$Q.$ A coloring that uses exactly  the set $P\ne\emptyset$ of colors
where $P\subset [n]$ is thus included in all nodes such that  $P\subseteq
Q$ for a total weight of

$$\sum_{P\subseteq Q \subseteq [n]} (-1)^{|Q|} =
\sum_{q=0}^{n-|P|} {n-|P|\choose q} (-1)^{n-q-|P|} = 0.$$

On the other hand a coloring using exactly $n$ colors is only included
in $Q=[n]$ with weight $(-1)^{n-|[n]|} = 1$ as required. Hence for
colorings with exactly $n$ colors we have

$$B_n = \sum_{Q \subseteq [n]} (-1)^{n-|Q|} A_{|Q|}
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} A_q.$$

We get the sequence

$$1, 2802750, 105904482864, 187226450755016, 61150982606571900,
\ldots$$

We can also compute $B_n$ using Stirling numbers of the second kind
from the cycle index and we obtain

$$B_n = \frac{n!}{24}
\left({26\brace n} + 9 {14\brace n}
+ 8 {10\brace n} + 6 {8\brace n}\right).$$

With this representation we see that the sequence is finite. For $n=26$
the formula evaluates to $26!/24$ because all orbits have the same
size, containing $24$ colorings.